# Calculating group score in Stata

Tags: stata

I have three variables: Household_ID, Age and Score.

My goal is for Stata to calculate a score (for each household) based on the ages of household members in the following way:

Add 0.5 if member is over 14, add 0.3 if member is 14 or below. I also want to increase the score by 0.5 if there is at least one member older than 14.

In the end, the Score variable should have the same value for each household member (e.g., 1.5 for an adult couple with no kids).

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on @TheIceBear's helpful data example, this is a shorter solution. I can't see why this shouldn't be done in place.

```
* Generate test data
clear
input float(hhid age)
1 25
1 24
1  7
2 12
2 10
3 18
3 17
3  2
4 35
4 14
end

gen score = cond(age <= 14, 0.3, 0.5)

egen hh_score = total(score), by(hhid)

bysort hhid (score) : replace hh_score = hh_score + 0.5 if score[_N] == 0.5 

list, sepby(hhid)
     +-------------------------------+
     | hhid   age   score   hh_score |
     |-------------------------------|
  1. |    1     7      .3        1.8 |
  2. |    1    24      .5        1.8 |
  3. |    1    25      .5        1.8 |
     |-------------------------------|
  4. |    2    10      .3         .6 |
  5. |    2    12      .3         .6 |
     |-------------------------------|
  6. |    3     2      .3        1.8 |
  7. |    3    17      .5        1.8 |
  8. |    3    18      .5        1.8 |
     |-------------------------------|
  9. |    4    14      .3        1.3 |
 10. |    4    35      .5        1.3 |
     +-------------------------------+
```

I've not addressed the question of what to do if any age is missing, except that here it will be assigned 0.5.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `preserve`/`restore` to calculate this in HH level data and then merge back to individual level.

```
* Generate test data
clear
input float(hhid age)
1 25
1 24
1  7
2 12
2 10
3 18
3 17
3  2
4 35
4 14
end

* Perserve the data
preserve
    
    * Gen dummy for hh member being above 14
    gen above_14 = (age > 14)
    
    * Calculate the individual score
    gen     score = 0
    replace score = 0.3 if above_14 == 0
    replace score = 0.5 if above_14 == 1
    
    * Collapse to hh level. Sum individual score and 
    * make dummy 1 if any hh member is above 14
    collapse (sum) score (max) above_14, by(hhid)
    
    * Add the score for any hh member above 14
    replace score = score + .5 if above_14 == 1
    
    * Keep only ID var and score
    * (more important in a bigger dataset than this test data)
    keep hhid score
    
    * Save teh HH level score in a tempfile
    tempfile hh_score
    save    `hh_score'

* Restore back to the state before preserve
restore

* Merge the hh score with the original data
merge m:1 hhid using `hh_score'
```